# angular 13でcsvファイルをアップロードする方法

Tags: angularjs, angular

angularの勉強をしています。
csvファイルを下記のソースコードでアップロードするように作成しましたが、
特に画面何も表示されず真っ白な状態です。
バージョンによって表示されないでしょうか。

参考URL
[Angular Upload Readcsv | stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upload-readcsv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
[Read CSV and convert JSON Data in Angular](https://www.eduforbetterment.com/read-csv-and-convert-json-data-in-angular/)

**app.component.ts**

```
/*
https://www.eduforbetterment.com/
*/
import { Component, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class CsvData {
    public id: any;
    public min: any;
    public max: any;
    public score: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  public records: any[] = [];
  @ViewChild('csvReader') csvReader: any;
  jsondatadisplay:any;

  uploadListener($event: any): void {

    let text = [];
    let files = $event.srcElement.files;

    if (this.isValidCSVFile(files[0])) {

      let input = $event.target;
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);

      reader.onload = () => {
        let csvData = reader.result;
        let csvRecordsArray = (<string>csvData).split(/\r\n|\n/);

        let headersRow = this.getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArray);

        this.records = this.getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray, headersRow.length);
      };

      reader.onerror = function () {
        console.log('error is occured while reading file!');
      };

    } else {
      alert("Please import valid .csv file.");
      this.fileReset();
    }
  }

  getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray: any, headerLength: any) {
    let csvArr = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < csvRecordsArray.length; i++) {
      let curruntRecord = (<string>csvRecordsArray[i]).split(',');
      if (curruntRecord.length == headerLength) {
        let csvRecord: CsvData = new CsvData();
        csvRecord.id = curruntRecord[0].trim();
        csvRecord.min = curruntRecord[1].trim();
        csvRecord.max = curruntRecord[2].trim();
        csvRecord.score = curruntRecord[3].trim();
        csvArr.push(csvRecord);
      }
    }
    return csvArr;
  }

//check etension
  isValidCSVFile(file: any) {
    return file.name.endsWith(".csv");
  }

  getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArr: any) {
    let headers = (<string>csvRecordsArr[0]).split(',');
    let headerArray = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      headerArray.push(headers[j]);
    }
    return headerArray;
  }

  fileReset() {
    this.csvReader.nativeElement.value = "";
    this.records = [];
    this.jsondatadisplay = '';
  }

  getJsonData(){
    this.jsondatadisplay = JSON.stringify(this.records);
  }


}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Upload csv to read
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

      <input type="file" #csvReader name="Upload CSV" id="txtFileUpload" (change)="uploadListener($event)"
        accept=".csv" />

    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="javascript:;" *ngIf="records.length > 0" (click)="getJsonData()" class="btn btn-primary">Convert Json </a>

  <a href="javascript:;" *ngIf="records.length > 0" (click)="fileReset()" class="btn btn-primary">Reset </a>

  {{jsondatadisplay}}
  <table class="table" *ngIf="records.length > 0">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Min</th>
        <th scope="col">Max</th>
        <th scope="col">Score</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let record of records;let i = index;">
        <th scope="row">{{record.id}}</th>
        <td>{{record.min}}</td>
        <td>{{record.max}}</td>
        <td>{{record.score}}</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
.table,.container{
  margin-top:20px; 
}
.btn{
  margin-right:20px; 
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: タグの説明もよく読んでください。これらはバージョンによって使い分けるので同時に指定するものではありません。

Comment: すいません、どのタグのことでしょうか。スタックオーバーフローのことでしょうか。

Comment: 質問に付与しているタグを指しています。